# Display bottom of page after clicking button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010/C# to develop my ASP.NET web project. I want my users to view bottom of page after clicking on a button. How can I do so? Can I use JavaScript, and if so, what is the function I should use?

Comment: guess you mean button, not bottom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an Anchor tag?

The Link

```
<a href="#bottom">bottom</a>
```

This would be at the bottom of the page:

```
<a name="bottom"></a>
```

If you want this behavior on an ASP.NET control like a `<asp:button>` and not a regular link for your button, then on the PostBack in your code-behind, you'd need to do something like below to spit out some JavaScript to jump the user down to that position.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Anchor", "location.hash = '#bottom';", true);
```

Comment: Quick easy and simple to implement. Thank you! Question is is there any way to to a smooth scroll rather than just bring the page to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [html anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html) tag to link to an anchor at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to use client side HTML Anchor, links with:

```
href=#bottom
```

see here for info: http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm